# How to randomize a switch?

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

This is what I have so far. The point of this program is if someone puts numbers `1..3`, they will get one of the prizes, but I don't want the prizes to be behind the same door each time.  How do I make them random, so maybe the million dollars is behind door 2 instead of door 1?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int doorNumber;
    //int door1, door2, door3;

    cout << "Pick a door, 1, 2, or 3" << endl;
    cin >> doorNumber;

    switch (doorNumber) {
    case 1:
        cout << "you win a million dollars" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "you win detergent" << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "you win a dishwasher" << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't think of a good way to do this, but +1 cause I think it's a good question. Off the top of my head, you could ignore their input and simply print a random statement. So rather than having `switch(doorNumber)`, get a random number and `switch` that instead

Comment: Your program could "cheat". I.e. Ignore input and just randomly determine which prize the user received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a random modifier to the player's selection. If you do this before hand, it will be exactly the same as having differnt predetermined door numbers for each prize. Once you do the switch, just add them together and make sure the result is between 1 and 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int doorNumber;
    //int door1, door2, door3;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumber = rand() % 3;
    // generate a number between 1 and 3

    cout << "Pick a door, 1, 2, or 3" << endl;
    cin >> doorNumber;

    switch ((doorNumber + randomNumber) % 3 + 1) { 
    case 1:
        cout << "you win a million dollars" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "you win detergent" << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "you win a dishwasher" << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You cannot have different door numbers within the switch because the case values are set during the compile, so they must be constant values.

Answer (score 2):

The case statements require integral value which must be known at compile-time, so you cannot randomly shift the doors numbers in your switch statement unfortunately. 
However, you could add a random number to the input of the user and modulo with 3 and add one to project the sum back to 1,2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Put the prizes in an array, and then shuffle that array, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    string prizes[3] = {"a million dollars", "detergent", "a dishwasher"};
    int doorNumber;

    std::random_shuffle(prizes, prizes+2);

    do {
        std::cout << "Pick a door: 1, 2, or 3" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> doorNumber;

        if ((doorNumber >= 1) && (doorNumber <= 3))
            break;

        std::cout << "Invalid door! Try again" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.clear();
    }
    while (true);

    std::cout << "you win " << prizes[doorNumber-1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `std::random_shuffle()` was deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17.  You can use `std::shuffle()` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    string prizes[3] = {"a million dollars", "detergent", "a dishwasher"};
    int doorNumber;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(std::begin(prizes), std::end(prizes), g);    

    do {
        std::cout << "Pick a door: 1, 2, or 3" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> doorNumber;

        if ((doorNumber >= 1) && (doorNumber <= 3))
            break;

        std::cout << "Invalid door! Try again" << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.clear();
    }
    while (true);

    std::cout << "you win " << prizes[doorNumber-1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd just remove the deprecated example, it doesn't add anything to this answer

Comment: @thecoshman: A lot of people don't use C++14/17 yet, so `std::random_shuffle()` is a viable solution in C++11 and earlier.

Comment: The question is simply tagged 'C++' and is apparently by a noob. We should avoid teaching old crappy ways of doing things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That may be true, but considering that most of those people should be more experienced (ie: they haven't switched because it wasn't around when they started), the person in question (as well as likely most people who look for answers here) should be using the latest code standards because there is no good reason for them not to.

Comment: That is your opinion. I prefer to not make assumptions and provide solutions for multiple versions unless told otherwise.

Comment: If the question wanted to target old version of C++ it would use those tags.

Comment: That is your opinion. I have mine. You have your answer, I have mine. Lets leave it at that. Good day.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by declaring an array and shuffling the content of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int doorNumber;
    int a[2] = {1,2,3};
    //int door1, door2, door3;

    random_shuffle(&a[0], &a[2]);

    cout << "Pick a door, 1, 2, or 3" << endl;
    cin >> doorNumber;

    switch (doorNumber) {
    case a[0]:
        cout << "you win a million dollars" << endl;
        break;
    case a[1]:
        cout << "you win detergent" << endl;
        break;
    case a[2]:
        cout << "you win a dishwasher" << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use runtime values for `case` statements, they must be compile-time constants. You will have to use `if` statements instead: `if (doorNumber == a[0]) { ... } else if (doorNumber == a[1]) { ... } else if (doorNumber == a[2]) { ... }`

Comment: `switch(a[doorNumber - 1]) { case 1: ... }` after ensuring that the number is between 1 and 3 inclusively.

Comment: Wasn't random shuffle removed or deprecated recently?

Comment: @pTz btw, editing to add a comment on the code isn't really 'appropriate', just leave a comment on the answer.

Comment: @Isaiah: yes, deprecated in C++14, removed in C++17.  There is `std::shuffle()` in C++11 and later, though.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot 'randomize a switch' like you are asking. Further, in the question you are asking, each time the program is run, the user enters one number and a random result is displayed; you may as well not even record what their input is and instead `switch` on a random value.

however, I suspect what you want to do is allow the player to multiple chances to pick doors. In this case, you need to create an collection of door results (in your example, a `std::vector<std::string>`) and then randomise it. C++, and many other languages, offer standard functions to shuffle collections. Now you have your randomly ordered collection of doors, you can allow players to pick them one by one and you can display the result of their choice.

Ultimately, I don't think you need a switch or to worry about how to randomise it.

ps, I've not done a code example for this as I think it's a theoretical enough concept, though I may not have explained it that well, so feel free to ask for clarification.

The C++ would be something like

```
std::vector<std::string> doors = {
    "door a", "door b", "door c"};
auto random_doors = std::shuffle_sort(doors); // or something like this
cout << "Enter a door: "
cin >> players_input
cout << "You entered a door and : " << random_doors[players_input];
```

Comment: how would i apply std::vector<std::string>. I'm still new to c++ and would need further instruction..

Comment: I've added a crude example, but you _really_ need to go out and learn what these things are yourself. Lots to learn yeah, I know, but just start reading.

Comment: You could also use std::array<std::string, 3> which works very similar to C style arrays.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `std::shuffle_sort()` in the STL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, don't really care that much, it should be thought of more as pseudo code that looks close to C++. The important part of this question is the logic not the actual implementation. Feel free to make it 'real' C++ if it matters to you though.

Comment: Ergh... for those who aren't dry corporate drones, please check the revision history of this answer, there used to be a touch of humanity. All praise the mindless masses.